# Access a Google Cloud VM (mysql) on Google DataStudio

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, remote-access, looker-studio

Im trying to connect Google Data Studio on my Mysql database located on a Google Cloud virtual machine but im getting error. Error code: f0631df4

I have opened the mysql to accept remote connection on virtual machine and in vpc firewall.

If i try to connect through remote mysql workbench, the connection works, but not on Google Data Studio.

There's any trick to do this?

Comment: Did my suggestion below fix the issue for you Fábio?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the firewall is blocking data studio IPs from reaching the database.

Google published a list of IP ranges that you should allow in this article:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en